# Can't link static library in XCode 4 in workspace

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, static-libraries, workspace

So, I'm working on a project and can't get my XCode 4 workspace to behave.  I have the main application as one project in the workspace. I then add the static library project into the workspace. It seems like everything is working okay. I can import files from the other project. It builds, but when I run it, I get this:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_iGBC
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/CD00CC83-28E4-4467-96C0-0D1777E21FDA/GBA4iOS.app/GBA4iOS
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /var/mobile/Applications/CD00CC83-28E4-4467-96C0-0D1777E21FDA/GBA4iOS.app/GBA4iOS
```

And crashes. It appears that although Xcode believes the library has been linked, and it builds and runs, the app doesn't *actually* have the library.  But in the derived data folder, it looks like everything that should be there... is there.

[image]

I'm going insane with XCode and all it's nuances in settings. Are there sanity checks I can go through to ensure this is working properly? What else can I do?

**Edit:**
Project settings are valid, and I've already linked the libraries.
[image: Libraries]

**Edit 2:**
My workspace is setup so the libraries are also in the workspace:
[image: Workspace]

I have removed the lib.a file from the main project and removed it from the Build Phase section, and added it back numerous times. There is no "copy library into destination folder" option when adding it in this way, so I can't do that.

Comment: You also need to add the lib to `Build Phases` => `Link Binary with Libraries`. And at `Summary` you have a button `Validate Settings`. I wonder if that helps for your case.

Answer (score 0):

try clean your build, if it don't work, remove the library in build phase and your project folder. When adding the lib to your project, check "copy item to destination if needed", the add that lib in build phase.

Comment: Updated. I've tried this a few times to no avail. Cleaned, and Clean Build Folder.

Comment: make sure your lib is OK, try linking another lib in the same way, if it works, may be there are some problem with your lib. It looks like you've refered to a class which is not in the lib. Linker says "Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_iGBC"